# Publish a Universal Binary iOS Framework in Swift using CocoaPods

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoapods

Created a framework in xcode, now want to install using POD. I created a binary zip of my framework. And uploaded it one of my repository. Now got stuck how to proceed. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can see a sample podspec which downloads framework binary from a http url.

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
      s.name             = "FRAMEWORK_NAME"
      s.version          = "VERSION"
      s.summary          = "SUMMARY"

      s.description      = "DESC"

      s.homepage         = "HOMEPAGE"
      s.license          = { :type => 'LICENSE_TYPE', :text => "COPYRIGHT" }
      s.author           = { "AUTHOR" }
      s.source           = { :http => "HTTP_FILE_PATH.zip"}

      s.platform         = :ios, 'DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'
      s.requires_arc     = true

      s.vendored_frameworks = 'SDK_NAME.framework'
      s.public_header_files = ["SDK_NAME.framework/Headers/*.h"
      s.frameworks = 'SDK_NAME'
      s.xcconfig = { "FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS"=> "\"$(PODS_ROOT)/SDK_NAME\"" }

end
```

Comment: My problem is that the vendors_frameworks item isn't in the pods folder, nor is it referenced so I'm getting a `No such module` error in the app trying to use the framework. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you check the source url? When you enter this url to the browser you should download the zip file for framework.